# Virtualbox holding down CTRL key

Tags: virtualbox

When my virtual machine is running, it seems like my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is held down. 
I want to SSH to my vm using Putty, my password has 'm' in it, but whenever I type m, the password is sent.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> is the default Host key in VirtualBox. Try changing it to some other key (for example <kbd>Application</kbd> key, ie. the one that opens context menu). You can do it in the VBox global settings (not VM properties).